# show "share with friends" dialog with the new Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook

is it possible to show a "share with friends" dialog with the new Facebook Javascript SDK?

i'm using a frame-based application.

in another app this feature looks something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use `fb:request-form` with `fb:multi-friend-selector` :

```
<fb:request-form action="http://fbrell.com/echo"
                 method="POST"
                 invite="true"
                 type="Echo Type"
                 content="Echo Content. <fb:req-choice url='http://fbrell.com/echo?choice=echo' label='Echo Label' />">
  <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false"
                            bypass="cancel"
                            cols=4
                            actiontext="Echo Action Text"/>
</fb:request-form>
```

[See it in action](http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:server-fbml-multi-friend-selector)

Comment: @choise then you need `fb:request-form` and `fb:multi-friend-selector`: http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:server-fbml-multi-friend-selector

Comment: yes, thats it. thanks. please can you change your post with this? thanks!